# Saving Date in NSUserDefault gives incorrect values

Tags: ios, swift

When I print the value that has been stored in `NSUserDefaults`, I get the following output.

```
    let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    prefs.setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "ST")

    print ("Hey \(prefs.objectForKey("ST")) ")
```

> Hey Optional(2016-10-24 08:29:20 +0000)

There's a text `Optional(` displayed and what I want is to display only the `Date time`.

In addition, the time given is incorrect. How can i solve this ?

Comment: Its taking UTC time I thinks that's why time is wrong

Comment: @Jecky How can I solve this, and How can I get rid of the text `Optional` that wraps around the Date-Time ?

Comment: Handling optionals is the *basics* of Swift. Explained here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330

Comment: It's just the default behavior of XCode that show the Optional text to let you know that the variable is a optional. For the time, the `print` command shows the time in UTC time, not in your local time. Look at: `+0000`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can save your date as a *formatted* String

let formatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"

```
// Save Date...
let hoy: Date = Date()

let formato_hoy = formatter.string(from: hoy)
print(formato_hoy)


// Recover Date...
let future_format: String = "2016.10.24 09:54:22 +0200"

if let future = formatter.date(from: future_format) 
{
    print(future)   
}
```

The ZZZ value in mask is related to time zone.